# dovecot says that userdb has missing details

Tags: email-server, dovecot

When I try to connect to dovecot via outlook I get this error:

> ERR:[AUTH]:authentication failed

here is the log files:

```
Sep 16 12:23:32 hostname9727 dovecot: auth: Error: passwd-file /etc/maillpass: User aaaa is missing userdb info
Sep 16 12:23:35 hostname9727 dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=<aaaa>, method=PLAIN, rip=77.114.47.11, lip=30.220.108.9, session=<oF81YqI83gBNfC8L>
Sep 16 12:26:02 hostname9727 dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=14751 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 16 12:26:02 hostname9727 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.10 starting up for imap, pop3 (core dumps disabled)
Sep 16 12:26:11 hostname9727 dovecot: auth: Error: passwd-file /etc/maillpass: User aaaa is missing userdb info
Sep 16 12:26:13 hostname9727 dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=<aaaa>, method=PLAIN, rip=77.114.47.11, lip=30.220.108.9, session=<ykSja6I8AQBNfC8L>
```

and here is the password database:

```
aaaa:1234
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide information on your configuration, for example the output of `doveconf -n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
aaaa:1234
```

That is not a **user database**, as the error message states you're clearly missing more than a few fields there for that.

That format could indeed be a **password database** but then you still need to define in your configuration file the other required fields that are normally found in the user database.  Please refer to the manual: http://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile how to use the password database as the template to derive the userdb fields from.

Lastly, you may have obfuscated your password hash, but if the clear text password for user aaaa is supposed to be `1234` I would expect something like:

```
aaaa:{plain}1234
```

Comment: see also https://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes for securely hashing your passwords with `dovecot`. For example to hash with `bcrypt` use `doveadm pw -r 15 -s BLF-CRYPT`